# Angular JS , $watch and web performance

Tags: angularjs

I want to ask one question, suppose my web page is like a text editor, I have some boxes where user can write.
Suppose i want to implement autosave in angular . I have  some ng-models for the info inside those boxes, and now i use ng-watch to listen to all of my boxes models.
So ,In a normal user mode ng-watch is continuously getting that my models are changing.
Will this method produce low performance in my web app?
If it did,Would you recommend me a way to implement an autosave on angular.

-----------EDIT---------

in brief :  what i want to know is, if used $watch for multiples scopes who are continuously changing can affect to the web page performance

Comment: Plugin for angularJS text editor. http://textangular.com/

Comment: well, my scope is more complex, and my webapp is not exactly a text editor, what i want to know, is if used $watch for multiples scopes who are continuously changing can affect to the web page performance

Comment: Could `ng-change` be a possible better alternative? Or do you need immidiate **live** updates to your scope the moment they type?

Comment: Instead of using a watch, you could use ng-change. And to avoid saving for each and every change, you could use the debounce feature of ngModelOptions: the change function would be called only after some period of inactivity of the user. Or you could simply use an interval that saves every N seconds. Or both. The web page performance is not what I would fear. What I would fear is sending hundreds of requests to the backend to save every keystroke.

Comment: live updates will be great for me, but ng-change could  help! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can only bind the text to the model via `ng-model` and make a timer with some interval you want. That timer would then post the status to the backend.

About the performance, ng-watch will, as you said fire **very** often. You'll probably want traffic to the backend every keystroke.

Hope it helps! Ask for more info if you want :)

**EDIT:**
If you want **live** updates, you should look at something like socket.io.

**EDIT 2:**
I would not either fear for the performance, but for simplicity. I've used `ng-watch` a few times, and everything becomes harder to debug. 
Cheers!

Comment: i understand continuously call the backend will affect to performance, in my case i'm not calling the backend just perform changes in others scopes

Comment: i know i have lot of ways to implement it, but as I say the question just for curiosity is, if $watch in multiples scope can affect to web performance

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of $watch'ing the models, you may opt for "ng-change" OR ng-blur instead.
If you use ng-change, then you may also set a timer, that will only re-evaluate your model once user stops typing for a second.

ng-blur triggers only once, after user is done typing and blurs/unfocuses the input.

Note: If you dont want to send autosave requests to the backend too often, you may autosave in client side ( using localStorage ), which would be instant. Then, you can send that final saved info to your sever once user is done with editing and submits a form/is ready to continue.